# How do I change the scaling pivot point in scaleTransition

Tags: javafx-11

I am currently learning javafx and I am trying to animate a line that scales in the x-direction.
My goal is for the line to start at point A and scale to point B.

Currently, I am creating a line, and animating it with ScaleTransition.
The problem is that it does not scale to point B, it scales from the center outwards in both directions

It seems like the scaling pivot is in the center of the line which makes it scale equally in both directions.
How do I make the line behave in the way I want it to?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Line line = new Line();
        line.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        line.setStrokeWidth(20);
        line.setStartX(400);
        line.setStartY(300);
        line.setEndX(410);
        line.setEndY(300);
        
        ScaleTransition scaleTransition = new ScaleTransition();
        scaleTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        scaleTransition.setNode(line);
        scaleTransition.setByX(10);
        scaleTransition.setCycleCount(20);
        scaleTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
        scaleTransition.play();

        Group root = new Group(line);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
```